# How does a SPA stores PKCE code_verifier?

Tags: reactjs, oauth, single-page-application, pkce

Considering Authorization Code Flow with PKCE **inside an iframe** as follows:

```
                                             +-------------------+
                                             |   Authz Server    |
   +--------+                                | +---------------+ |
   |        |--(A)- Authorization Request ---->|               | |
   |        |       + t(code_verifier), t_m  | | Authorization | |
   |        |                                | |    Endpoint   | |
   |        |<-(B)---- Authorization Code -----|               | |
   |        |                                | +---------------+ |
   | Client |                                |                   |
   |        |                                | +---------------+ |
   |        |--(C)-- Access Token Request ---->|               | |
   |        |          + code_verifier       | |    Token      | |
   |        |                                | |   Endpoint    | |
   |        |<-(D)------ Access Token ---------|               | |
   +--------+                                | +---------------+ |
                                             +-------------------+
```

How does a SPA application (React, for instance) can store a `code_verifier` as when a **(B)** callback occurs (considering a 302 redirection or `window.location.replace`) the page reloads and the state (original `code_verifier`) is lost?

How to implement this flow as same as a native mobile application, without storing `code_verifier` in a backend and just keep it in memory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to use any backend to keep the code verifier, you can utilise [session storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage). Local storage will be blank when you come back from the Authorization Server to your SPA, but data in session storage will still be available, as long as you stay on the same tab.

Comment: The idea of Authorization Code Flow with PKCE is to avoid someone get hold of the authorization code through the URL. If putting the code_verifier in the session storage, one diminishes the risk of intrusion, but if an intruder would access your session storage, he'd be in. 

Have I understood it right? Is there any way to mitigate this in a SPA, or is the risk always there to some extent?

Comment: You got it right. PKCE is meant to protect you from situations where someone manages to intercept the authorization code in transit. Thanks to PKCE the attacker won't be able to exchange the code for tokens, because they don't know the verifier. If they manage to break into your app and read the session storage, then they can probably already do much more than just intercept the code.

Comment: Local storage won't be blank, the difference is actually that while data in local storage doesn't expire, the data in session storage will expire after the session ends (i.e., tab is closed). Reference [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)